# regex look around on either side (two words are nearby each other within certain distance, regardless of order)

Tags: r, regex

My goal is to use `grepl` and pattern to find words matches in sentences. The `pattern` would be to match two words that are nearby each other (say, up to 2 words between them, regardless of order). See the example data and my expected results in the code chunk below.

**Problem**
My test function (code bellow) was reported an error, it says **invalid regular expression**. The problem seems to be in the second part (i.e., `pat2`), or specifically here `(?<=(?:resource.?\\b|basic service|property))\\s(?:\\w+\\s){0,2}(?=(?:access to|\\brights to))`. I wonder what the issue is, as I did not see much difference between pat2 and pat1 in my function. If there are more elegant ways to achieve this, that would be much appreciated too!

```
## my function

condition1 <- "\\s"                 ## a space after the 1st word    
condition2 <- "(?:\\w+\\s)"         ## a word character with a space after it
 
lookaround_nearby_n <- function(word1, word2, n){
  pat1 <- paste0("(?<=", word1, ")", 
              condition1,                 
              condition2,            ## other strings after the space (`condition2`)
              "{0,", n, "}",         ## Matches `condition2` at most n times  
              "(?=", word2, ")")     ## the 2nd word
  
  pat2 <- paste0("(?<=", word2, ")", 
                condition1,                 
                condition2,            ## other strings after the space (`condition2`)
                "{0,", n, "}",         ## Matches `condition2` at most n times  
                "(?=", word1, ")")     ## 
  pat <- paste(pat1, pat2, sep = "|"); 
  return(pat)
}


w1 <- "(?:access to|\\brights to)"
w2 <- "(?:resource.?\\b|basic service|property)"

pat <- lookaround_nearby_n(word1 = w1, word2 = w2, n = 2)
pat

## test data
dataframe <- data_frame(mytext = c('SD is access to property',
                                   'SD is access to x1 property',
                                   'SD is access to x1 x2 property',
                                   'SD is access to x1 x2 x3 property',
                                   'SD property access to sth',
                                   'SD property x1 access to sth',
                                   'SD property x1 x2 access to sb',
                                   'SD property x1 x2 x3 access to sb'))

grepl(pattern = pat, x = dataframe$mytext, ignore.case = T, perl = T)

## I expect to get "T, T, T, F, T, T, T, F" from the above example.
```

Comment: If you are interested in boolean result only, do not use a lookbehind, use a regular consuming pattern. Remove the lookbehind.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/RK4fr6

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you give me an example to fix my code? I am new to regex, and I still have not figured out how to use these properly. Thanks!

Comment: It is helpful to readers if you begin questions with a statement of what you wish to do, without reference to code or algorithmic approaches, using one or more examples for illustration when you think that would be helpful. When giving an example always show the desired result. Without such a statement readers must reverse-engineer your code to discover the problem being addressed. As is, I do not understand the problem you wish to solve with your code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your advice. I have edited my question again - hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of your function, without look behind should work:

```
lookaround_nearby_n <- function(word1, word2, n){
  condition = paste0("\\s(?:\\w+\\s){0,",n,"}")
  paste0("(",word1,condition,word2,")","|",
         "(",word2,condition,word1,")")
}

w1 <- "(access to|rights to)"
w2 <- "(resource|basic service|property)"

pat=lookaround_nearby_n(w1,w2,2)

grepl(pattern = pat, x = dataframe$mytext, ignore.case = T, perl = T)
```

Output

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Neat! Works well for the example! The only potential issue might be that this could match something like "We access to x1 access to" or "we have rights to access to" (I do not expect there are such sentences in real life though).

Comment: I've updated the answer to avoid that